# roslaunch, rosrun, and ./mynode.py

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a trivial single node scenario (for example in python) I believe I could run it in any of the above three ways. A launch file is obviously overkill if I am still designing and experimenting. But is there anything wrong with just running it from the command line assuming it's dependencies are satisfied?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298916/roslaunch,-rosrun,-and-./mynode.py/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each one had its own advantage.  we generally use the roslaunch when we have multiple scripts to work. If you want to run the single script then rosrun is enough. The advantage of running these commands is, no need to worry about the path of script/s. you can run the command (rolaunch, rosrun) from anywhere.

there are other possibilities is also like `python mynode.py`. So there is no harm to use the anyone mentioned.

Yes, in case of `rosservice` it can

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-31**:
Thanks. All clear, but I don't understand your last sentence

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-07-31**:
in case of rosservice, your client should run before the server. if you keep these script in the launch file, then this can cause an issue.